# How do I share custom mobile Form Factors with other developers?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile

I know I can create custom Form Factors in Visual Studio, but how do I export them (not available in "Tools | Import and Export Settings")?

If I set a WM form to use a custom Form Factor, save it in the repository, then someone else on the project gets that form from the repository it defaults back to "Windows Mobile 6 Classic".

I know there has to be an XML/XSLT file somewhere that stores my custom settings but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

On Windows 7 it can be found in: \Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\CoreCon\1.0\conman_ds_platform.xslt.

On Windows XP it can be found in: \Documents and Settings\{username}\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\CoreCon\1.0\conman_ds_platform.xslt.